# ¿Como puedo centrar verticalmente elementos cono CSS dentro de una GRID?

Tags: css, grid

```css
header {
    background-color: #18162C;
}
.nav-box {
    background-color: rgb(36, 32, 80);
    width: 60%;
    margin: auto;
    height: 90px;
}
.image {
    width: 54px;
}
.nav-box ul li a {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.nav-box ul {
    text-align: center;
}




/* Aqui el Codigo de Css GRID */

.box-grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    grid-gap: 20px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="nav-box">
            <ul class="box-grid">
                <li><a href="#"><img class="image" src="./logo.png" alt=""></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">lorem</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">lorem</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">lorem</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>
```

Quisiera saber como centrar los elementos de forma vertical dentro de una GRID con Css mas que todo una imagen aquí les dejo el código y una imagen de como se ve.
Vi varios vídeos pero en general no aplican cuando están dentro de una GRID o en Responsive no se adaptan bien y quisiera saber como hacer de la mejor forma posible.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si a los items del menu las imagenes y ese texto, mas se me complica esa imagen

Comment: Quería que estén centrados en el contenedor de forma vertical y horizontalmente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se puede hacer con las propiedades `align-content` y `align-items`, pero además necesitas darle al `grid` la altura del contenedor:

```css
header {
    background-color: #18162C;
}
.nav-box {
    background-color: rgb(36, 32, 80);
    width: 60%;
    margin: auto;
    height: 90px;
}
.image {
    width: 54px;
}
.nav-box ul li a {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.nav-box ul {
    text-align: center;
}




/* Aqui el Codigo de Css GRID */

.box-grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    grid-gap: 20px;
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="nav-box">
            <ul class="box-grid">
                <li><a href="#"><img class="image" src="./logo.png" alt=""></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">lorem</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">lorem</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">lorem</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>
```

Comment: Excelente muchas gracias, se alineo todo correctamente y adaptable al Responsive

Answer (score 0):

lo que puedes hacer es aplicarle a la clase CSS .nav-box lo siguiente:

```
.nav-box {
    background-color: rgb(36, 32, 80);
    width: 60%;
    margin: auto;
    height: 90px;
    display: grid;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Ahora se verá centrado verticalmente con solo aplicarle los atributos `display: grid;` y `align-items: center;`.

Comment: Gracias esa propiedad fue la que funciono.